# ibm visual configuration explorer build failed

Tags: configuration, ibm, websphere, explorer

I am trying to generate WebSphere configuration using Headless ISA VCE, however after launching command I get the Build Failed message referring to non-existing build.xml file

**Command:**

```
java -jar startup.jar wasexporter/wasexport.xml -Dwas.root=/usr/WebSphere/AppSrv -Dprofile.name=Dmgr01
```

**Output:**

> Buildfile: /usr/WebSphere/AppSrv/vce/build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED Buildfile: /usr/WebSphere/AppSrv/vce/build.xml does not
>   exist
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

Could you please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer on my own.

There are few xml files distributed together with Headless VCE. I reused one of them called

```
automation-example.xml
```

so the command looked like following:

```
java -jar startup.jar -buildfile automation-example.xml \
-Dwas.root=/usr/WebSphere/AppSrv -Dprofile.name=Dmgr01
```

all required data was collected and stored in **./wasconfigs/example.configuration**  file called example.configuration